# glossaries in French

Tags: glossaries, babel, french, xindy

I try to get a glossary in French. So I started with a sample (in english) from `glossaries` package. I run `latex` then `makeglossaries` then `latex` (x2), everything was fine with the sample. I run the same sample using `xindy` option for the `glossaries` package and adding `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` like it's suggested in the guide of glossaries package, everything is working very well.

But here start my problem, if I change spanish by french, I get an error message from xindy:

`ERROR: 
Syntax Error in 
(INDEXENTRY :TKEY (:|EMPTYSET@INDEXeNDCSNAME|) :LOCREF "{}{11}" :ATTR
 "pageglsnumberformat").`

Here is my latex code :

```
 \documentclass{report}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[xindy,toc,acronym]{glossaries}

% Define a new glossary type called notation
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}

\makeglossaries

% Notation definitions


\newglossaryentry{not:emptyset}{type=notation,
name={$O$},
text={00},
description={The empty set},
sort={O}}

% Main glossary definitions


\newglossaryentry{gls:card}{name=cardinality,
description={The number of elements in the specified set}}

% Acronym definitions

\newacronym{nf}{NF}{new foundations}

\begin{document}
\title{Sample Document using the glossaries Package}
\author{Nicola Talbot}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\printglossaries

\chapter{Introduction}

$\gls{not:emptyset}$ 

\gls{gls:card}

\gls{nf}
\end{document}
```

I goggled this but I found nothing.
Please, someone can help me?

Comment: Did you try to remove the `.ind`, `*.ilg` and `.xdy` all files related to `glossaries` before switching to the new language?

Comment: I do not have such files. But even if I remove all the temporary files, I get the same error message.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What version of `glossaries` are you using? The only error I get with your example (thank you for providing it) is caused by `babel` making `:` active. If you replace the `:` characters in the labels with something else (for example a period) or simply remove them, the example works fine for me.

Comment: I removed the `:` from labels, and that works fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, it's a common problem: high punctuation (`; : ! ?`) is made active by frenchb and that creates problems in labels and the like. One solution is to systematically replace `:` with, e.g.  `-`. Or you compile with `XeLaTeX`, replacing babel with `polyglossia`: no character is made active in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Converting my comment into an answer.)

When `babel` is used with the `french` setting, the colon `:` is converted into an active character. The glossary entry labels are used to form internal commands that store the entry data, so they can't contain any active characters. Removing the colons or replacing them with a non-active character fixes the problem. For example, replacing them with a period works fine:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[xindy,toc,acronym]{glossaries}

% Define a new glossary type called notation
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}

\makeglossaries

% Notation definitions


\newglossaryentry{not.emptyset}{type=notation,
name={$O$},
text={00},
description={The empty set},
sort={O}}

% Main glossary definitions


\newglossaryentry{gls.card}{name=cardinality,
description={The number of elements in the specified set}}

% Acronym definitions

\newacronym{nf}{NF}{new foundations}

\begin{document}
\title{Sample Document using the glossaries Package}
\author{Nicola Talbot}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\printglossaries

\chapter{Introduction}

$\gls{not.emptyset}$ 

\gls{gls.card}

\gls{nf}
\end{document}
```